# I wan to get the physical address corresponding to a logical address in the C program.An error occurred when I mapped the page address

Tags: linux-kernel

Here is the relevant piece of source code:
......

```
static unsigned long vaddr2paddr(struct seq_file *m, unsigned long vaddr,int pid)
{
    pte_t *pte_tmp = NULL;  
    pmd_t *pmd_tmp = NULL;  
    pud_t *pud_tmp = NULL;  
    pgd_t *pgd_tmp = NULL;  
    struct task_struct *pcb_tmp = NULL;
    unsigned long paddr = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO"in vaddr2paddr try to find the task %d .\n",pid);  
    pcb_tmp =pid_task(find_get_pid(pid),PIDTYPE_PID); 
    if(!pcb_tmp) {
         printk(KERN_INFO"Can't find the task %d .\n",pid);
         return 0;
    }
    
  pgd_tmp = pgd_offset(pcb_tmp->mm, vaddr);
  if (pgd_none(*pgd_tmp)) {
      printk("not mapped in pgd\n");
      return -1;
  }
```

/*73*/

```
pud_tmp = pud_offset(pgd_tmp, vaddr);  
  if (pud_none(*pud_tmp)) {
      printk("not mapped in pud\n");
      return -1;
  }


  pmd_tmp = pmd_offset(pud_tmp, vaddr);
  if (pmd_none(*pmd_tmp)) {
      printk("not mapped in pmd\n");
      return -1;
  }


  //pte = pte_offset_kernel(pmd, vaddr);
  pte_tmp = pte_offset_kernel(pmd_tmp, vaddr);    
  if (pte_none(*pte_tmp)) {
      printk("not mapped in pte\n");
      return -1;
  }
  
 ......
}
```

error: passing argument 1 of ‘pud_offset’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]

73 |   pud_tmp = pud_offset(pgd_tmp, vaddr);

```
                 pgd_t * {aka struct <anonymous> *}
```

expected ‘p4d_t *’ {aka ‘struct  *’} but argument is of type ‘pgd_t *’ {aka ‘struct  *’}

925 | static inline pud_t *pud_offset(p4d_t *p4d, unsigned long address)

***I have made the following changes, but there was a segfault later.***

```
static unsigned long vaddr2paddr(struct seq_file *m, unsigned long vaddr,int pid)
{
    pte_t *pte_tmp = NULL;  
    pmd_t *pmd_tmp = NULL;  
    pud_t *pud_tmp = NULL;
    p4d_t* p4d_tmp = NULL; 
    pgd_t *pgd_tmp = NULL;  
    struct task_struct *pcb_tmp = NULL;
    unsigned long paddr = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO"in vaddr2paddr try to find the task %d .\n",pid);  
    pcb_tmp =pid_task(find_get_pid(pid),PIDTYPE_PID); 
    if(!pcb_tmp) {
         printk(KERN_INFO"Can't find the task %d .\n",pid);
         return 0;
    }
    
  pgd_tmp = pgd_offset(pcb_tmp->mm, vaddr);
  if (pgd_none(*pgd_tmp)) {
      printk("not mapped in pgd\n");
      return -1;
  }


 p4d_tmp = p4d_offset(pgd_tmp, vaddr);
 if (p4d_none(*p4d_tmp))
     return 0;
    
  pud_tmp = pud_offset(p4d_tmp, vaddr);  
  if (pud_none(*pud_tmp)) {
      printk("not mapped in pud\n");
      return -1;
  }
    

  pmd_tmp = pmd_offset(pud_tmp, vaddr);
  if (pmd_none(*pmd_tmp)) {
      printk("not mapped in pmd\n");
      return -1;
  }
    


  //pte = pte_offset_kernel(pmd, vaddr);
  pte_tmp = pte_offset_kernel(pmd_tmp, vaddr);    
  if (pte_none(*pte_tmp)) {
      printk("not mapped in pte\n");
      return -1;
  }
 
}
```

***If you can directly help modify the code, I would be very grateful.***

Comment: Why do you want this?  Physical addresses are of no use unless you are doing DMA, and in that case there are existing APIs to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743052/getting-error-when-compiling-kernel-for-page-table-walk

Comment: I am a student. Out of the need of learning. I made changes according to that article, but there was a segfault later.

Comment: Certainly if you try to DO anything with a physical address, it's going to explode.  There are no CPU instructions that deal with physical addresses, except for loading CR3.  I notice that you don't return anything at all from this function.

Comment: asm( " mov %%cr3, %%rax \n mov %%rax, %0 " : "=m" (_cr3) :: "ax" );I want to print out the address but there is a segfault

Comment: User programs can't access the page tables.  Kernel code can access the page tables, but user virtual addresses are not mapped into the page tables except while performing a syscall from the user program.  You seem to be passing in a pid, so I'm guessing the VA is not mapped to the currently running task.